# Refresh php page after updating xml file to be parsed by that page

Tags: php, xml, refresh, simplexml, reload

I found that contents parsed with SimpleXML in a PHP page doesn't refresh when I load an updated XML file.

```
$xmlnewsm = simplexml_load_file('../xml/newsm.xml');
```

On the pc refreshing manually the page works and it gives me updated contents, on my mobile phone (HTC One M7/Chrome for Android) it doesn't work.

I tried `header("refresh: tempo;");` and `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` inside the page but they don't work.

Comment: How do you load the xml content?

Comment: this way: $xmlnewsm = simplexml_load_file('../xml/newsm.xml');

Comment: What if you try loading `simplexml_load_file('../xml/newsm.xml?t='.time());` ?

Comment: I tried simplexml_load_file('../xml/newsm.xml?t='.time()); and simplexml_load_file('../xml/newsm.xml?t='.time(2)); and with both it doesn't load anything...

Comment: Forget my earlier comment, have you tried setting cache headers in your php file or in the html header? Look at example 2 here for instance: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: I'm not totally sure yet, but I think this trick did the job.